# Create request random subdomains on different servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to create subdomains in random route53 on different servers (without AWS secret/acesss key). I have one script, and when the server makes a request, that server specific subdomain will be created. What are the best services that I can use for this? I'd like to hear your ideas too.

Comment: Sorry, but it is difficult to understand what you are wanting to do/achieve. Are you simply asking how to create a subdomain in Amazon Route 53 via a script?

Comment: A script will generate a random subdomain and a record will be entered in route53 with the server's ip address. But without access/secret key. Considering doing this with Api Gateway. Is it good idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by "But without access/secret key"? Are you saying that you want to create the record in Amazon Route 53 without using AWS credentials? Yes, you could create an API Gateway that receives an HTTP request and triggers an AWS Lambda function to create the subdomain. However, I'd recommend some form of security on the API Gateway request to avoid unauthorized requests (somehow).